# Media Manager | External Metadata Field Values get in DD4T

Tags: dd4t, media-manager

I am trying to get the External Metadata field values from the video component loaded from Media Manager inside CMS using DD4T but it does not show any propery in DD4T view. I want to use GUID field of this video to create URL. Do i need to install any addOns to access this field in DD4T

[image]

Or there is any other way to access the media manager video component as internal link?

Answer (score 4):

This external metadata is not added by default.
You have the following options

- you can define a normal metadata field in your External content stub schema, and add some event system logic to copy the necessary fields from external metadata to your regular metadata fields. This is explained by Bart Koopman in the following blog : http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/ecl-event-handlers
- you can add some custom TBB's to your dd4t templates that read the external metadata, and add these fields to your dd4t xml. You can find some sample code for this option here https://gist.github.com/bkoopman/6436263 (also code written by the great Bart Koopman)

The advantage of the first option is that the metadata properties are seen as "real" metadata, so as an added bonus, you can use these fields in broker queries.

The second option might be easier to implement, as you will only need to add a template building block. The disadvantage here is that these metadata fields won't appear in the broker custom meta table.

Comment: Thanks Harald Hoffelinck for the reply. I will try one of these approaches and let you know if the issue is resolved.